# Looking for a chat website for improving Spanish

Tags: spanish

Is there any chat website for Spanish learners to improve their Spanish? (But please If they strictly prohibit annoying content)

Answer (score 1):

What about HelloTalk?

I use it to learn Japanese, talking with Japanese native speakers and if you post things you can even add a tag”help me learn language “, then people would come and help. They are nice, and also could get new friends.

There are also Spanish speakers there, including native speakers.

Answer (score 0):

People in Latin America massively use WhatsApp groups. So you can find a group in Spanish about a topic you like.

You have many apps and websites to find people speaking the language you learn (Tandem, HelloTalk, Interpals,…).